# Return JSON value from a function

Tags: json, function, return

I am able to pass a JSON string to my function but can't return a value back.

```
var json = {"First":"ABC", "Middle":"DEF", "Last":"GHI"};
allFunction6(json);
alert(first); //this does not work

function allFunction6(json) {
    var first = json.First;
    alert(first); //this alerts "ABC"
    return first;       
}
```

Does the variable not retain its value outside of the function, or am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: That's not a JSON string. That's a Javascript object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the variable does not retain its value outside of the function, because that is where it is scoped to, the function.

You need to save the returned value.

```
var storedReturnValue = allFunction6(json);
```